# How to sort only one column without changing the others?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have this example dataframe:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,  ~A,  ~B,  ~C,  ~D,
   1L, "a", "d", "a", "a",
   2L, "b", "c", "b", "b",
   3L, "c", "b", "c", "c",
   4L, "d", "a", "d", "d")
```

I want to sort only column `B` in ascending order without changing any other column.

Desired output:

```
     id A     B     C     D    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     a     a     a    
2     2 b     b     b     b    
3     3 c     c     c     c    
4     4 d     d     d     d
```

I have tried `arrange`:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(B)
```

Here all other columns also change as expected.

Is there a way to only sort one column, although it might be against the logic of a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(B = sort(B))

     id A     B     C     D    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     a     a     a    
2     2 b     b     b     b    
3     3 c     c     c     c    
4     4 d     d     d     d
```

Answer (score 1):

base

```
df$B <- sort(df$B)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id A     B     C     D    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     a     a     a    
2     2 b     b     b     b    
3     3 c     c     c     c    
4     4 d     d     d     d
```